# Form Validation & Honeypot - Is my code right?

Tags: javascript, validation, honeypot

I've been using the form verification below successfully so far. It has required fields, email validation and a honeypot for spam. However, one of my client is getting blank form results when really the form should not be submitted at all. So maybe I'm not seeing the obvious. It's pretty simple code I think. Can anyone take a quick look and let me know if I missed something?

On a different note, are spam robots getting smarter than honeypots?

This is the JS:

```
<script>
function verify() {
    var themessage = "You are required to complete the following fields: ";
    var x=document.form.email.value
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (document.form.address.value!="") {
        themessage = "You are not human! No form for you!";
    }

    if (document.form.first_name.value=="") {
        themessage = themessage + " - First Name";
    }

    if (document.form.last_name.value=="") {
        themessage = themessage + " - Last Name";
    }

    if (document.form.email.value=="") {
        themessage = themessage + " - E-mail";
    }

    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        themessage = "You need to enter a valid email address";
    }

    //alert if fields are empty and cancel form submit
    if (themessage == "You are required to complete the following fields: ") {
        document.form.submit();
    }

    else {
        alert(themessage);
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="output.php">
    <div id="input">
        <div id="field">First Name:</div>
        <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name">
    </div>

    <div id="input">
        <div id="field">Last Name:</div>
        <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name">
    </div>

    <div id="input">
        <div id="field">Email:</div>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    </div>

    <div class="input address"><!-- This is the Honeypot -->
        <div id="field">Address:</div>
        <input name="address" type="text" id="address">
    </div>

    <div id="input">
        <div id="field">Phone:</div>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
    </div>

    <div id="input">
        <div id="field3">Comments:</div>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="verify();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting blanks into the fields (apart from email) will produce a seemingly empty form result

Comment: The form results were all blank including the email field, which tells me that something is not right in the code or robots are now smarter and have ways to go around validation.

Based on my code, if the First Name and Last Name are blank the form shouldn't go thru, right?

Comment: By blanks I meant chr(32). But if email was blank also, my suspicion is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably only using client-side validation of the form data, which is bad.

Bots do not run JavaScript, so they ignore your `verify` function and simply send the form as it is written in pure HTML.

In general, you should always give server-side validation a higher priority, for security reasons and because the user might have disabled JavaScript in his browser settings.

Doing these kinds of validations in JavaScript should be an optional feature for more usability, but it should never implement a security feature (like your "honeypot").

Comment: Thank you for your input. Any recommendation on where to find information on how to secure a form server-side?

Comment: There is A LOT of info about that on the internet, just search for "<your language> validate input". The OWASP created a [guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Guide_Project) which has an own chapter on data validation, etc.